# VSCode pipenv run REPL program receives environment activation causing initial syntax error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, task, virtualenv, pipenv

The auto-sourcing/enable of Python environment is a great feature! But I don't know how to disable it for tasks. Pyenv for example automatically activates and runs commands in its virtualenv, so I end up having errors for my pipenv run commands.
I've made a little GIF with the behavior.

[image]

For reference, this is my .vscode/tasks.json file

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "Run IPython Shell",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "pipenv run ipython",
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": true,
            "panel": "shared",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": false
        }
    }]
}
```

And the output is the following:

```
> Executing task: pipenv run ipython <

source /Users/nahuel/.virtualenvs/pysrv-RjlHvHY5/bin/activate
Python 3.6.6 (default, Aug  6 2018, 12:14:58)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: source /Users/nahuel/.virtualenvs/pysrv-RjlHvHY5/bin/activate
  File "<ipython-input-1-944ce73c2717>", line 1
    source /Users/nahuel/.virtualenvs/pysrv-RjlHvHY5/bin/activate
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [2]:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue in current versions of VSCode. The environment activation works for both pipenv and poetry, and can be customized from settings.